# Unicode variables shown using excapes, not as utf-8

Tags: unicode, python-sphinx

I am documenting variables in sphinx, which are `{unicode:uncode}` and `{unicode:float}` maps. Sphinx renders the value in an ugly way, with unicode escapes -- like this:

```
woo._units.unit = {
   u'rad': 1.0, u'MN': 1000000.0, u'\u2030': 0.001, u'g/cm\xb3': 1000.0,
   u'MN\xb7m': 1000000.0, u'mm\xb3': 1e-09, u'mm\xb2': 1e-06, u'Pa': 1.0,
   u'year': 31536000.0, u'%': 0.01, u'kN\xb7m': 1000.0, u'-': 1.0, u't/h': 0.2777777777777778
}
```

(The whole rendering is at http://woodem.eu/doc/woo._units.html)

How can I force Sphinx to encode unicode strings with UTF-8 and put them straight to the HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain but I would think this has to do with `repr()`. Since you cannot change the behaviour of repr on built-in types and since a few searches of the [docs](http://sphinx-doc.org) turned up nothing, I would think that this is not easily fixed if it can be fixed at all.

If you haven't already tried it though, add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your file and see if that works. I doubt it will since that's usually used to in files to configure sphinx, but it is worth a shot.